# What should be the bootable USB size to be a blackarch live?

Tags: arch-linux, live-usb

I tried to make a live USB for blackarch with a 16GB USB flash. It boots up correctly, but the working after booting is much different. Like on right click, it doesn’t show the correct options. I get options to deal with workspaces on a right click.
On VirtualBox, same iso file works correctly, on right click I get options of accessing various tools.
Also, I use a Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to burn the usb again but with DD this time (be careful, this command is also called "Disk Destroyer"):

```
sudo dd bs=512M if=file.iso of=/dev/sdX
```

Command found on the [BlackArch download page](https://blackarch.org/downloads.html).